# How to return JSON data from spring Controller using @ResponseBody

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-4

**Spring version 4.2.0, Hibernate 4.1.4**
Here is my `Controller` function:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mobile/getcomp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Company>  listforCompanies() {      
    List<Company> listOfCompanies= new ArrayList<Company>();        
    listOfCompanies = companyManager.getAllCompanies();
    return listOfCompanies;
}
```

Jackson JSON mapper dependency in `Pom.xml`:

```xml
    <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Getting the list in my `ArrayList`, but when returning the following error is shown:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/IrApp] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.ArrayList] with root cause
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.ArrayList
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:68)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:124)
```

[Link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/) to the example I'm following.

Comment: can you post your spring configuration plz ?

Comment: @RafikBELDI mate every thing is fine is spring config not able to add too much code in question as it demands description.

Comment: My problem was that all getters was private.

Comment: Thanks, @peter . My getters were package-private, but they needed to be public.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Add the below dependency to your pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: made my day, just spent more the 4 hours and no one has even mentioned this any where.

Comment: Adding the dependencies was the key for me! Thanks!

Comment: The dependecies was the key for me too. I wonder why don't they write them down in Spring's page howto: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html

Comment: worked for me too! A little note for users passing by and always choose to use the last version of the dependency instead of the mentioned here. DO NOT USE THE LAST VERSION for jackson dependecy! I've tried with 2.7.0-rc1 and didn't work. With 2.6.3 worked just fine.

Comment: This magically solved my problem with the RequestBody deserialization as well. notably the error "content-type not supported" - just vanished.

Comment: @rmpt Thanks for warning, I tried 2.7.0 just now, and it is not working, downgraded to 2.6.3 and it works fine, heh...

Comment: Thanks gus, Any idea on why it not worked with 2.7.x. Its wasted my time for long.

Comment: Can you confirm if the answer with checking that getters (setters) works? It seems odd that dependencies have been omitted from the documentation.

Comment: This isn't the case with spring4.x. Only adding getter/setters is enough.

Comment: What getters/setters?

Comment: For me only changing the version to 2.7.9 worked. I'm using Spring 4.3.4.RELEASE.

Comment: In this case, add getter/setter for class members of Company class or any POJO which is being returned in your case.

Comment: I'm using Spring 4, and adding this dependency resolved this issue.

Answer (score 110):

I was facing same issue. I did not put `@ResponseBody` since I was using `@RestController`. But still I was getting error because I did not put the `getter/setter` method for the Company class. So after putting the `getter/setter` my problem was resolved.

Comment: Adding just the getter was sufficient.

Comment: This is the correct answer. One should not add more dependencies.

Comment: Thanks the same worked for me. But little surprised how that really matters.

Comment: Worked for me. In my case setting field access to public worked as well.

Comment: yes this works. Spring should fix that error to be more specific.

Comment: If you are using lombok, don't forget to put `@Data` for getters

Comment: I tried to add using Lombok getter and setter but it did not worked out until i added all conventional getters/setters. Any one have any idea on this??

Answer (score 12):

You also need to be sure that returned bean is not empty (and can be serialized by Jackson). In my particular case I tried to return an instance of an object without getters and setters and without any jackson annotation and with fields equals to null. I got following message:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
    No serializer found for class com.foo.bar.Baz and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )
```

Comment: This is more a comment (not an answer).

Answer (score 8):

When I was facing this issue, I simply put just getter setter methods and my issues were resolved.

I am using Spring boot version 2.0.

Comment: adding getter & setter will now fix the issue in this case

Answer (score 5):

Considering @Arpit answer, for me it worked only when I add two jackson dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

and configured, of cause, web.xml `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`.

Original answer that helped me is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33896080/3014866

Answer (score 4):

Yes just add the setters/getters with public modifier ;)

Answer (score 3):

I was using groovy+springboot and got this error.

> Adding getter/setter is enough if we are using below dependency.

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
```

As Jackson core classes come with it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using `jackson-databind-2.8.8.jar` that is not compatible with `JDK 1.6` I need to use so Spring wasn't loading this converter. I downgraded the version and it works now.