# Spring Boot Application: No converter found for return value of type

Tags: rest, spring-boot, ubuntu, converters

I am writing a simple `REST API` according to [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/) Spring-Boot tutorial. On my local dev machines (`Ubuntu 15.04` and `Windows 8.1`) everything works like a charm.

I have an old `32-bit` `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS` server lying around on which I wanted to deploy my `REST` service.

The starting log is ok, but as soon as I send a `GET` request to the `/user/{id}` endpoint, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class ch.gmazlami.gifty.models.user.User
```

And then down the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

The entire stacktrace is posted [here](http://pastebin.ca/3263361).

I looked into some answers referring this error, but those don't seem to apply to my problem, since I'm using Spring-Boot, no `xml` configs whatsoever.

The affected controller is:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(@PathVariable Long id){
    try{
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(userService.getUserById(id), HttpStatus.OK);
    }catch(NoSuchUserException e){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. It is very weird since the exact same things work on other machines perfectly.

Comment: solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719142/how-to-return-a-set-of-objects-with-spring-boot/46977580#46977580

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you should make some changes to your pom.xml and mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml files:
Add the following dependecies to your pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

and update your mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
     <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
   </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: FYI, using Spring Boot `1.4.0.RELEASE` all I needed was the dependencies.

Answer (score 33):

This happened to me, on one resource only (one method) and I did not understand why. All methods within classes in the same package, with the same annotations, same call to `ResponseEntity.ok(...)` etc. just worked.

But not this one.

**It turns out I had forgottent to generate the getters on my POJO class !**

As soon as I had added them it worked.

Hopefully it can save somebody some time eventually...

Comment: This fixed my problem too.  If anyone tracking this post is still having issues, check your POJO getter's closely; in my case, I had a lower-cased getter on one property; instead of the expected camel case:  gettargetObject() instead of getTargetObject()

Comment: Same with me..I had forgotten to add getters in my POJO class.  Plus1

Comment: Works like a charm. with SpringBoot 2.0+, no need to manually add dependency for jackson, no need to register MessageConverter manually, what u need is just getters for ur POJO.

Answer (score 9):

This happens when you forget the "build" call:

```
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```

should be:

```
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).build();
```

Answer (score 5):

I meet with this problem, because I omitted `Getters` and `Setters` method.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the rest of the answers: the methods must be ***public***.

My IDE flagged that the methods could be "package only", prompting me to remove the "public" portion of the declaration (which I foolishly did).

I added `public` to my methods and solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was using IntelliJ Idea and its auto-generated getters and setters. Since I had a boolean field called `success`, the getter was named `isSucccess()`. I renamed it `getSuccess()` and the error went away.