# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

With this code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bar/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<foo> foo() {

        Foo model;
        ...
        return ResponseEntity.ok(model);
    }
}
```

I get the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type
```

My guess is that the object cannot be converted to JSON because Jackson is missing. I don't understand why because I thought that Jackson was built in with spring boot.

Then I have tried to add Jackson to the pom.xml but I still have the same error

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Do I have to change any spring boot properties to make this work?

Comment: solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719142/how-to-return-a-set-of-objects-with-spring-boot/46977580#46977580

Comment: Use Central repository to download jars
If you are not maven user here you can find your required version jars
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/

Answer (score 355, accepted):

The problem was that one of the nested objects in `Foo` didn't have any `getter/setter`

Comment: it needs only getters

Comment: This resolved my issue also.  If anyone continues receiving a Converter error, it the most likely cause is that Jackson cannot find/process the necessary getter(s).   Check your POJO getter's closely!  In my case, I had a lower-cased getter on one property instead of the expected camel case:  getmetaTag() instead of getMetaTag()

Comment: Also make sure that the getter/setters are `public`! (Or if you, like me, are using immutable classes, make sure your fields are `public final` not just `final`)

Comment: Thanks your answer helped, but in my case I had two identical json property names assigned to two separated fields. i.e. @JsonProperty("id")... @JsonProperty("id").
Looks like this error gets thrown whenever the jackson serializer fails.

Comment: You can also makes class attributes public if you do not want to add getters.

Comment: This answer might be specific to Spring Framework. I'm almost positive I didn't run into this issue when using JAX-RS and JBoss (I assume it used reflection to get the values instead of accessors).

Answer (score 23):

Add the below dependency to your pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0.pr3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: spring boot web starter contains Jackson dependency as default.

Comment: Yes, but we need to override the version, there its needed

Comment: I think @heemin is right, we don't need jackson-databing dependency separately when use spring boot. Thanks

Answer (score 17):

Add the getter/setter missing inside the bean mentioned in the error message.

Answer (score 14):

Use `@ResponseBody` and `getter/setter`. Hope it will solve your issue.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bar/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<foo> foo() {
```

and update your `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
     <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
   </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: it's spring-boot. I don't have a mvc-dispatcher-servlet. Do you know if there's a property for that?

Comment: Use getter/setter for foo class

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. The problem is the object that I send not that I receive. There's no getter/setter

Comment: @Marc Please go through this tutorial: http://sanjayingole.blogspot.com/2015/10/no-converter-found-for-return-value-of.html

Comment: Yeah but this is spring. I'm using Spring boot. The configuration is different

Comment: For Spring boot, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33832735/spring-boot-application-no-converter-found-for-return-value-of-type

Comment: Where do I set the message-converters. I don't have a mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

Comment: @Marc I know this wasn't your problem, but you can add message converters by adding a `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConverters` bean with a `@Bean` annotated method in your `@SpringBootApplication` class. You can see this by just reading the `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoconfiguration` class, the Spring boot autoconfiguration code is incredibly readable and often the quickest way to figure out problems like these

Comment: Adding "MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" worked for me. Thanks man. I am using Spring 4.2.5 and was facing this problem. I added above converter in WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.

Answer (score 8):

The answer written by @Marc is also valid. But the concrete answer is the `Getter` method is required. You don't even need a `Setter`.

Answer (score 5):

The issue occurred in my case because spring framework couldn't fetch the properties of nested objects. Getters/Setters is one way of solving. Making the properties public is another quick and dirty solution to validate if this is indeed the problem.

Answer (score 5):

@EnableWebMvc annotation on config class resolved my problem. (Spring 5, no web.xml, initialized by AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer)

Answer (score 3):

I had the very same problem, and unfortunately it could not be solved by adding getter methods, or adding jackson dependencies.

I then looked at Official Spring Guide, and followed their example as given here - https://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/ - where the example also shows the conversion of returned object to JSON format.

I then again made my own project, with the difference that this time I also added the dependencies and build plugins that's present in the **pom.xml** file of the Official Spring Guide example I mentioned above.

The modified dependencies and build part of XML file looks like this!

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

You can see the same in the mentioned link above.

**And magically, atleast for me, it works. So, if you have already exhausted your other options, you might want to try this out, as was the case with me.**

Just a side note, it didn't work for me when I added the dependencies in my previous project and did Maven install and update project stuff. So, I had to again make my project from scratch. I didn't bother much about it as mine is an example project, but you might want to look for that too!

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error for a while.I had verify getter methods were available for all properties.Still was getting the same error.
To resolve an issue Configure MVC xml(configuration) with

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

.This is required for Spring to detect the presence of jackson and setup the corresponding converters.

Comment: Thanks mate, it works!

I just put it in the applicationContext.xml file.

Answer (score 2):

While using Spring Boot 2.2 I run into a similiar error message and while googling my error message

> No converter for [class java.util.ArrayList] with preset Content-Type 'null'

this question here is on top, but all answers here did not work for me, so I think it's a good idea to add the answer I found myself:

I had to add the following dependencies to the `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
  <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

After this I need to add the following to the WebApplication class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebApplication
 {
  // ...

  @Bean
  public HttpMessageConverter<Object> createXmlHttpMessageConverter()
   {
    final MarshallingHttpMessageConverter xmlConverter = new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter();
    final XStreamMarshaller xstreamMarshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
    xstreamMarshaller.setAutodetectAnnotations(true);
    xmlConverter.setMarshaller(xstreamMarshaller);
    xmlConverter.setUnmarshaller(xstreamMarshaller);
    return xmlConverter;
   }

}
```

Last but not least within my `@Controller` I used:

```
@GetMapping(produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType. APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
@ResponseBody
public List<MeterTypeEntity> listXmlJson(final Model model)
 {
  return this.service.list();
 }
```

So now I got JSON and XML return values depending on the requests `Accept` header.

To make the XML output more readable (remove the complete package name from tag names) you could also add `@XStreamAlias` the following to your entity class:

```
@Table("ExampleTypes")
@XStreamAlias("ExampleType")
public class ExampleTypeEntity
 {
  // ...
 }
```

Hopefully this will help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my case i'm using spring boot , and i have encountered a similar error :

```
No converter for [class java.util.ArrayList] with preset Content-Type 'null'
```

turns out that i have a controller with

```
@GetMapping(produces = { "application/xml", "application/json" })
```

and shamefully i wasn't adding the  `Accept` header to my requests

Comment: This solved the problem changed this     `@RequestMapping(value = "/", produces = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)` to this  `@RequestMapping(value = "/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`

Answer (score 2):

you didn't have any getter/setter methods.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was returning Boolean in Response Entity
and had :

```
produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE,
```

When i changed it to below

```
produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
```

It worked!

Example of what i had.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/xxx-xxxx",
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> yyyy(
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue for long time then comes to know have to convert object into JSON using Object Mapper and  pass it as *JSON Object*

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getTags", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getTags(@RequestParam String tagName) throws
        JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    List<Tag> result = new ArrayList<Tag>();
    for (Tag tag : data) {
        if (tag.getTagName().contains(tagName)) {
            result.add(tag);
        }
    }
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(result);
    return json;
}
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced such error when by accident put two @JsonProperty("some_value") identical lines on different properties inside the class

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot to add library jackson-core.jar, I only added jackson-annotations.jar and jackson-databind.jar. When I added jackson-core.jar, it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same error when the scope of the `jackson-databind` dependency had been set to `test`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.9</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Removing the `<scope>` line fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Faced same error recently - the pojo had getters/setters and all jackson dependencies were imported in pom correctly but some how "< scope > " was "provided" for jackson dependency and this caused the issue. Removing " < Scope > " from jackson dependency fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem but I was using Lombok and my UploadFileResponse pojo was a builder.

```
public ResponseEntity<UploadFileResponse>
```

To solve I added @Getter annotation:

```
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class UploadFileResponse
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below dependency in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Was facing the same issue as the return type cannot be bind with the MediaType of Class Foo. After adding the dependency it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This might also happen due low Jackson version; e.g. Spring Boot 2.4 default Jackson version is too low when using Java records; you need at least 2.5 to serialize them properly.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same error on a Spring 5 project (not Spring Boot), by running a SpringMVC JUnit test-case on a method that returns `ResponseEntity<List<MyPojo>>`

Error: `No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.ArrayList`

I thought I had all the correct Jackson artifacts in my pom, but later realized that I had the legacy versions.  The Maven groupId changed on the Jackson jars from `org.codehaus.jackson`to `com.fasterxml.jackson.core`.  After switching to the new jars the error went away.

Updated maven pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Response Object Or its nested object(s), their attributes

- must be accessible either thru public getter/setter
- or making the attributes public directly

Answer (score -1):

You are missing an Annotation **`@ResponseBody`**