# War on Tomcat - Spring Vaadin Application

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, vaadin

I have deploy a Java application developed with Spring and Vaadin on a Apache Tomcat 8.0.39 service running on Windows Server 2012.

The war is correctly deploy but when I want to run application, i receive an error/exception :

Etat HTTP 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter for return value of type: class java.util.LinkedHashMap`.

A note says the stack trace is in the logs of Tomcat but I don't find them.

Therefore, I don't know where is the problem, I can't show the code corresponding. If you need something for understand, I can edit my post.

EDIT : The problem is the names of my views, I post an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841373/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-no-converter-found-for-return-value-of-type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the names of my views/pages in Vaadin.

On my computer, with Spring, I have a name for each view, and it is ok.

But on Tomcat, he wants a page without any name, in other words, a page name "".

I change the login page from "login" to "";

And then all run perfectly.

It works !