# No converter found for return value of type - Spring Rest API with db call

Tags: java, spring, rest

**EDIT: I figured out how to fix this and posted it in an answer below.**

I'm trying to create an API that queries a db and returns two values. I know the db query works because I can see it spit the values out to the console. But when I execute it, I get this error: No converter found for return value of type: class hello.GetPatientInfo

Here is my controller code:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class PatientInfoController {

    @RequestMapping("/patientinfo")
    @ResponseBody
    public GetPatientInfo getPatientInfo (@RequestParam String ssnum){
        return new GetPatientInfo(ssnum);
    }
}
```

Here is my class for it:

```
package hello;

import com.automation.dataprovider.DatabaseFunctions;

public class GetPatientInfo {
    DatabaseFunctions db = new DatabaseFunctions();
    private final String pname;
    private final String patno;

    public GetPatientInfo(String ssnum){
        this.patno = getPatNo(ssnum);
        this.pname = getPname(ssnum);

    }

    public String getPatNo(String ssnum){
        String query = "SELECT PATNO FROM lib.PATIENTS WHERE SSNUM = '" + ssnum +"'";
        String patno = db.returnSingleValue(query).toString();
        System.out.println(patno);
        return patno;
    }

    public String getPname(String ssnum){
        String query = "SELECT PNAME FROM lib.PATIENTS WHERE SSNUM = '" + ssnum +"'";
        String pname = db.returnSingleValue(query).toString();
        System.out.println(pname);
        return pname;
    }
}
```

I'm sure I'm doing something fundamentally wrong since I've never created an api before but I'm just not getting anywhere quick. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide the full stack trace? It is probably related to the mapping unable to convert your object to json format.

Comment: As @PedroMadrid already mentioned. It seems like Spring cannot map yout Java Object to JSON. You should always try return just a single wrapper objects with no functionality.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return JSON data from spring Controller using @ResponseBody](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905917/how-to-return-json-data-from-spring-controller-using-responsebody)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong, I needed to pass in the two variables so that they would get set then returned.

```
private final String pname = "";
    private final String patno = "";

    @RequestMapping("/patientinfo")
    @ResponseBody
    public GetPatientInfo getPatientInfo (@RequestParam String ssnum){
        return new GetPatientInfo(pname, patno, ssnum);
    }
```

Doing so corrected the error that was being received.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make your class `GetPatientInfo` independent from the database. You should always return only a wrapper class for information of your database. So the wrapper class should not make the database calls at all.

So you could do something like this. 
    package hello;

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.automation.dataprovider.DatabaseFunctions;

@RestController
public class PatientInfoController {



@RequestMapping("/patientinfo")
@ResponseBody
public GetPatientInfo getPatientInfo (@RequestParam String ssnum){
    DatabaseFunctions db = new DatabaseFunctions();
    String pname = db.returnSingleValue("SELECT PNAME FROM lib.PATIENTS WHERE SSNUM = '" + ssnum +"'";).toString();
    String patno = b.returnSingleValue(SELECT PATNO FROM lib.PATIENTS WHERE SSNUM = '" + ssnum +"'").toString();
    return new GetPatientInfo(pname, patno);
}
```

And then in **GetPatienInfo**

```
package hello;

import com.automation.dataprovider.DatabaseFunctions;

public class GetPatientInfo {
DatabaseFunctions db = new DatabaseFunctions();
private final String pname;
private final String patno;

public GetPatientInfo(String pname, String patno){
    this.patno = patno;
    this.pname = pname;

}

public String getPatNo(){
    return this.patno;
}

public String getPname(){
    return this.pname;
}
}
```

And like @Bob Drinks mentioned in his comment: Look at **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905917/how-to-return-json-data-from-spring-controller-using-responsebody)** to be sure you added the dependencies you need to return JSON.

Comment: The crucial part is adding a dependency on jackson-databind.