# Java - Spring return JSON object / array

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, controller

I have a basic Rest Controller which returns a list of models in json to the client:

```
@RestController
public class DataControllerREST {

    @Autowired
    private DataService dataService;

    @GetMapping("/data")
    public List<Data> getData() {
        return dataService.list();
    }

}
```

Which returns data in this format:

```
[

    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "data 1",
        "description": "description 1",
        "active": true,
        "img": "path/to/img"
    },
    // etc ...

]
```

Thats great for starting, but i thought about returning data of this format:

```
[
    "success": true,
    "count": 12,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "data 1",
            "description": "description 1",
            "active": true,
            "img": "path/to/img"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "data 2",
            "description": "description 2",
            "active": true,
            "img": "path/to/img"
        },
    ]
    // etc ...

]
```

But i am not sure about this issue as i can not return any class as JSON... anybody has suggestions or advices?

Greetings and thanks!

Comment: When your JSON starts with "[", that means its an array. Did you actually mean an array or did you mean an object (`{}`) with an array of `data` in it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"as i can not return any class as JSON" - says who?

In fact, that's exactly what you *should* do. In this case, you will want to create an outer class that contains all of the fields that you want. It would look something like this:

```
public class DataResponse {

    private Boolean success;
    private Integer count;
    private List<Data> data;

    <relevant getters and setters>
}
```

And your service code would change to something like this:

```
@GetMapping("/data")
public DataResponse getData() {
    List<Data> results = dataService.list();
    DataResponse response = new DataResponse ();
    response.setSuccess(true);
    response.setCount(results.size());
    response.setData(results);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks for answer,
i ment the "converter" which was complaining:
" org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class com.example.app.rest.controller.DataResponse "
do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you add the relevant getters and setters for DataResponse? Is [Jackson included as part of your project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905917/how-to-return-json-data-from-spring-controller-using-responsebody)?