# TypeError: this.state.persons.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am new to React.I am facing this error.I have the code which is pasted below.Please help get out of this error.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card} from 'semantic-ui-react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class PersonList extends React.Component {
state = {
    persons: []
}

componentDidMount() {

axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/locations`)
  .then(res => {
    const persons = res.data;
    this.setState({ persons });
  })
}

render() {
   return (
    <div class="ui stackable two column grid">
     { this.state.persons.map(person =>  
       <div class="column">
        <Card
          header={person.LOCATION}
        />
      </div>)
     }
    </div>
   )
 }
}
```

The error message is pasted below

```
TypeError: this.state.persons.map is not a function
PersonList.render
C:/Users/user/Desktop/src/Sample.js:22
19 | render() {
20 |   return (
21 |       <div class="ui stackable two column grid">
> 22 |        { this.state.persons.map(person =>  
23 |          <div class="column">
```

Output of `console.log('data', res.data)`:

```
{LOCATION: "CHINA9, SWEDEN9, CANADA9, austin, ", searchKey: {…}}
```

I request anyone to figure me out this error.

Comment: that means the data that you are getting from server is not an array, check that by `console.log(res.data)`, it should be `[]`

Comment: {LOCATION: "CHINA9, SWEDEN9, CANADA9, austin, ", searchKey: {…}} --- is the output of res.data . Will the locations be accesed in above code I mean will I be able to print CHINA9 etc.

Comment: that is an object that' why it was throwing error, how you want to print these values, expected output?

Comment: I want to print them in the Cards as you see in the above code ...A card for every location. Actually I am returning a Map<String,Object> from the server. Any idea how to return JSON from Spring Boot so that I can access here in React.

Comment: @dps plz check updated answer. which will display LOCATION in card header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array from the `LOCATION` string using `.split(',')` :

```
function render() {
  const locationArr = this.state.persons.LOCATION
    ? this.state.persons.LOCATION.split(',')
    : [];
  return (
    <div className="ui stackable two column grid">
      {locationArr.map((location) => {
        if (location !== ' ') {
          return (
            <div className="column">
              <Card header={location} />
            </div>
          );
        }
        return null;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I get the output but it prints a blank card as well.How do I get rid of that? For your reference {LOCATION: "CHINA9, SWEDEN9, CANADA9, austin, ", searchKey: {…}}

Comment: I edited my answer to handle the blank result but your server shouldn't send that.

Answer (score 0):

create constructor and declare your state

```
constructor(props){
     super(props);
     state = {
        persons: ""
     }
   }
```

change state update  to

```
axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/locations`)
  .then(res => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({ persons : res.data.LOCATION }));
  })
}
```

render method

```
this.state.persons.split(",").map((person, index) => (
    <div class="column" key={index}>
        <Card
          header={person}
        />
      </div>
))
```

Comment: there is no error with op's code, only issue is the data he is getting from server that is not an array. `state={}` is alternate way of defining the state values. also `prevstate` is not required in this case :)

Comment: might be issue with async setState ?

Comment: nope, issue is `res.data` is not any array, data that he is getting from server, you can also try `a.map(el => el)`, define a as any value other than `[]` it will throw the same error :)

Comment: yupp data might be not an array

Answer (score 0):

you set `this.state.persons` to `res.data` which is probably an object.. you cannot use `map` on an object...

instead you maybe want to push the the object to an array of objects. like this:

```
let persons = this.state.persons.slice()
persons.push(res.data)    
this.setState({persons})
```

Comment: there is no issue with that part, `this.setState({ persons })` is correct way and it will remains an array only.

Answer (score 0):

- First of all make sure that you are getting data from the server in the form of **array** because map only works on array.
- Secondly correct your code structure little bit.

  `render() {
   let {
       perons
   } = this.state.perons;
   if (perons.length == 0) {
       return (
           <div><h3>Loading data...</h3></div>
       )
   }
   return (
       <div class="ui stackable two column grid">
       { persons.map(person =>{
          return(

         <div class="column">
          <Card
            header={person.LOCATION}
          />
        </div>
        )
    });
       }
      </div>
   )
  }`

Comment: Actually I am returning a Map<String,Object> from the server. Any idea how to return JSON or as you say 'array' from Spring Boot so that I can access here in React.

Comment: Well i didn't use Spring Boot framework but you can **refer to these links** [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839753/returning-json-object-as-response-in-spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839753/returning-json-object-as-response-in-spring-boot) and [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905917/how-to-return-json-data-from-spring-controller-using-responsebody/35822500#35822500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905917/how-to-return-json-data-from-spring-controller-using-responsebody/35822500#35822500).
Hope it will be helpful.